# jQuery Wont Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a  element that I am trying to animate using jQuery when the page is scrolled. Im trying to have the element's background color change from transparent to a black color. Ive been trying different methods to accomplish this problem, but none of them have worked. Please help.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
    $("#heading").animate({
      backgroundColor: "rgb(10,22,18,0)"
    }, "slow");
  } else {
    $("#heading").animate({
      backgroundColor: "rgb(10,22,18,1)"
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

```css
#heading {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(10, 22, 18, 0);
}

.head {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.head2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.head2:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.font {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heading">
  <img class="head" id="mainImg" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Know Music">
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb1">Guitar</button>
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb2">Bass</button>
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb3">Piano</button>
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb4">Drums</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Added a condition to the JS to add a class once it is greater than 100 and remove the class when its below that. I tried toggleClass, but it was flickering. I added the `.change` class on the css to for the background color change and added a transition to the `#heading` id.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ter332b/) The backgroundColor cannot be animated using the animate function within jQuery unless you use a plugin. See [jQuery animate docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
    $("#heading").addClass(" change");
  } else{
  $("#heading").removeClass(" change");
  }
});
```

```css
html,body{height:3000px;}
#heading {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(10, 22, 18, 0);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out all;
}

.head {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.head2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.head2:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.font {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}


.change{
  background-color: rgba(10,22,18,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heading">
  <img class="head" id="mainImg" src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Know Music">
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb1">Guitar</button>
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb2">Bass</button>
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb3">Piano</button>
  <button class="head head2 font" href="" id="hb4">Drums</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if($(this).scrollTop()>= 100){
    // animate
 }else{
    // animate
 }
});
```